# On $\sup|\varphi^{-1}(n)|=+\infty$

Tags: number-theory, alternative-proof, pigeonhole-principle, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-series

I am trying to find an elementary proof of the following fact:

> Given some $N\geq 2$, there are $N$ distinct integers $a_1,\ldots,a_N$ such that $\varphi(a_1)=\ldots=\varphi(a_N)$ with $\varphi$ being Euler's totient function.

My original analytic proof goes as follows:
If the number of solutions of $\varphi(x)=N$ were bounded, the series
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2019}\frac{1}{\varphi(n)\log^2\varphi(n)}$$
would be convergent by comparison with $\sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{n \log^2 n}$ and condensation. It is enough to show that the last series is divergent. It is bounded below by a multiple of
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2019}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^2 \log^2(n)}$$
and since
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^{2+s}}=\zeta(s+1)\zeta(s+2)$$
for any $s>0$, it is enough to prove that the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\zeta(1+t+s)\zeta(2+t+s)\,ds\,dt $$
is divergent, or that the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} u\,\zeta(1+u)\zeta(2+u)\,du $$
is divergent. On the other hand this is trivial since $u\zeta(1+u)\zeta(2+u)\geq u$ for any $u>0$.

---

Alternative combinatorial proof: we may consider a very large $N$ and the numbers in $[N,2N]$ with at least $\log\log\log N$ prime factors. They have a positive density in $[N,2N]$, and they are mapped by the totient function into an interval with length $O\left(\frac{N}{\log \log N}\right)$. By the pigeonhole principle, at least $\Omega(\log\log N)$ elements of $[N,2N]$ share the same $\varphi$.

---

**I would be happier in having a combinatorial proof possibly not relying on subtle statements about the average order of $\omega(n)$ or Mertens' theorem about $\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p}$.**

Comment: Ok isn't this an open problem though? I mean it looks like a lemma that follows directly from Carmichael's conjecture, and so a rigorous proof of this would also need a proof of Carmichael's

Comment: @Adam: what is the open problem you are talking about? I believe my analytic proof clearly shows/proves that $|\varphi^{-1}(n)|$ is not bounded.

Comment: Carmicheal's conjecture states a different thing, i.e. that *every* value in the range of $\varphi$ is attained at least twice. I am just stating that there are values attained with arbitrary multiplicity.

Comment: Trying to simplify things as much as possible: if we manage to prove that
$$\varphi(n)\leq \frac{n}{\log\log\log n}$$
for almost every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we are done by invoking the pigeonhole principle. Since 
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}=\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\leq \exp\left(-\sum_{p\mid n}\frac{1}{p}\right) $$
it is enough to show that for almost every $n$
$$ \sum_{p\mid n}\frac{1}{p}\geq \log\log\log\log n$$
(here there are the last words of a number theorist close to drowning: "$\log\log\log\log$") holds, i.e. that almost every integer is "reasonably composite".

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ford's theorem states that for any $k$, there is $n$ with $|\varphi^{-1}(n)|=k$, while your question only asks about $\geq k$. I haven't looked up the proof of Ford's theorem, but I expect your problem can be solved in a much simpler way (and might have been known historically earlier)

Comment: @Wojowu: fine. Here it is another overkill: by Pillai's theorem, the set of values taken by the $\varphi$ function has density zero. It follows that $|\varphi^{-1}(n)|$ is clearly unbounded.

Comment: I was referring to the statement in the yellow box sorry I may have misinterpreted your aim here

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  typical that no one throws them a log too

Comment: @Adam: no harm done. Just to be clear, *there are $N$ distinct integers$\ldots$* in the yellow box stands for *there are at least $N$ distinct integers$\ldots$*

Comment: So... still not clear as to how the predicate of distinction isn't invoking a combinatoric argument built from Carmichael's mate I'll need you to explain how my interpretation is flawed there

Comment: @Adam: Carmicheal's conjecture plus Ford's theorem are stating that $\{|\varphi^{-1}(n)|:n\geq 2\}=\{2,3,4,5,\ldots\}$ while I am just stating that such set is unbounded.

Comment: Carmichael's states that for all $n$ there is at least one $m \not=n$ such that $\varphi(n)=\varphi(m)$ yes?

Comment: @Adam: yes. I am stating that no matter how large $N$ is, there are at least $N$ numbers with the same $\varphi$.

Comment: Ok well I haven't looked at Ford's for long enough maybe this is the issue here

Comment: Ah so you only seek to prove that the lower bound for $N$ distinct numbers with equal totient is $N$, and unbounded above?

Comment: Ok I think I see where ive missed the point now

Comment: Have you seen this thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109509/the-inverse-of-the-euler-totient-function/109511#109511

Comment: @SandeepSilwal: I am reading it now, thanks. The bound $N(n)\geq n^{5/9}$ infinitely often is pretty nice, but the Brun-Titchmarsh theorem is heavy artillery. On the other hand, I guess it is the natural extension of my argument below, just relying on $2\mid(p-1)$ for any odd prime $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is an elementary argument inspired by [Pillai](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183493596)$^{(*)}$: the point is that $\nu_2(\varphi(n))\approx\omega(n).$

Let $O^{\omega}$ the set of odd natural numbers with at least $\omega$ prime divisors and let $O^{\omega}_n=O^{\omega}\cap[1,n]$.
$O^{\omega}$ certainly has density $\frac{1}{2}$ for any $\omega$ - it is enough to invoke some elementary version of the PNT and basic sieving arguments. The totient function maps $O^{\omega}_n$ into a subset of $[1,n]\cap 2^{\omega}\mathbb{N}$, hence by the pigeonhole principle at least $(1-\varepsilon_n)2^{\omega-1}$ elements of $O^{\omega}_n$ share the same $\varphi$. Since $\omega$ is arbitrary we have finished.

<sup>His surname is pure magic: Sivasankaranarayana.</sup>